# What Should be done in place of the error showing on my sql table in the code below?

Tags: sql, asp.net, visual-studio-2019

```
    {
        using (RegistrationEntities1 dc = new RegistrationEntities1())
        {    
            var state = dc.tblState.ToList();  //It provides an error here pointing towards the table
            List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
            li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "--Select State--", Value = "0" });

            foreach (var m in state)
            {
                li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = m.statename, Value = m.stateid.ToString()});
                ViewBag.state = li;
            }
        }
    }
```

Error: CS1061   'RegistrationEntities1' does not contain a definition for 'tblState' and no accessible extension method 'tblState' accepting a first argument of type 'RegistrationEntities1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Is 'tblState' a publically accessable property ?

Comment: Where did you get this code snippet? Copy it from elsewhere or write it yourself? Did you add the `tblState` to the entity when you create `RegistrationEntities1`?

Comment: @Jayme yes it is accessable

Comment: @KyleWang I used a reference of a code and wrote this and yes I added the *tblState* when I created *RegistrationEntities1*

Comment: @shark Check if `DbSet<tblState>` exists in `model.Context.cs`?

Comment: @shark Maby share some of the RegistrationEntities1 class so we can help further please